# Comparing using isEqualToString not working with Url encoded strings in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using flickrApi in iPhone. After authenticiation, i get their userId as

```
inNSID = (_NSCFString) @"108346178%40N06"
```

Note the `%40`

In my app, I am saving the same id in my server. At some other place, where i have to authenticate again,  i use this id to check if authentication is already done or not., when i try to compare this string with my string using `isEqualToString` , the result is NO.

Here is log trace

```
Printing description of tempAcc->serviceId:
108346178%40N06
Printing description of inNSID:
108346178%40N06
```

Both seems to be exactly same, how can I compare both? What is going on here.

Comment: One trick to use is `NSLog(@"%@", @[ theString ])`. That is, make an array containing the string and log that instead of the string directly. The way that arrays print their description will cause any special characters to be escaped. I suspect you have a newline character or something in one of the strings.

Comment: yea ken is right you should look for spaces or new lines `NSLog(@"'%@'", @[ theString ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSRegularexpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to scan Unicode strings for any matches.

```
NSString *string = @"108346178%40N06";
NSError *error;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:string
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                options:NSMatchingReportCompletion
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

if (match) {
    NSLog(@"yes");

} else {
    NSLog(@"no");

}
```

Comment: Why bother with the error parameter if you aren't going to use it?